# Using Yandex map tiles in Google Maps v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have Yandex map tiles (Russian) working in Google Maps API v2 but something's not working in Google Maps API v3, see the following jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VkGjq/1/

Note that when switching between the Google road map and the Yandex tiles they don't line up & the marker is in the wrong position.

For Maps v2, I made an equivalent jsfiddle but it's broken since it needs an API key: http://jsfiddle.net/ggrgQ/1/

You can see similar code here, but you will have to navigate to Moscow manually as Yandex doesn't have any decent data outside of Russia: http://gpsloglabs.com/share/2367c16f3a0e75b05ac8a5529afba225dd929518/

I don't recall where I got the v3 code, but the constants appear to roughly correspond to the v2 version. Other than that, I don't understand what the projection is doing so I'm stuck.

Any ideas?

The code from the jsfiddle is as follows:

```
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(55.75, 37.62);
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: center,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: center});

map.mapTypes.set("Yandex",
                 new google.maps.ImageMapType(
                     {getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
                         return "http://vec0"+((coord.x+coord.y)%5)+".maps.yandex.net/tiles?l=map&v=2.16.0&x=" + 
                             coord.x + "&y=" + coord.y + "&z=" + zoom + "";
                     },
                      tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
                      isPng: true,
                      alt: "Yandex",
                      name: "Yandex",
                      projection: new YandexProjection(),
                      maxZoom: 17}));

map.setOptions({mapTypeControlOptions: {mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, "Yandex"]} });

function YandexProjection() {
    this.pixelOrigin_ = new google.maps.Point(128,128);
    var MERCATOR_RANGE = 256;
    this.pixelsPerLonDegree_ = MERCATOR_RANGE / 360;
    this.pixelsPerLonRadian_ = MERCATOR_RANGE / (2 * Math.PI);

    this.fromLatLngToPoint = function(latLng) {
        function atanh(x) {
            return 0.5*Math.log((1+x)/(1-x));
        }
        function degreesToRadians(deg) {
            return deg * (Math.PI / 180);
        }
        function bound(value, opt_min, opt_max) {
            if (opt_min != null) value = Math.max(value, opt_min);
            if (opt_max != null) value = Math.min(value, opt_max);
            return value;
        }

        var origin = this.pixelOrigin_;
        var exct = 0.0818197;
        var z = Math.sin(latLng.lat()/180*Math.PI);
        return new google.maps.Point(origin.x + latLng.lng() *this.pixelsPerLonDegree_,
                                     Math.abs(origin.y - this.pixelsPerLonRadian_*(atanh(z)-exct*atanh(exct*z))));
    };

    this.fromPointToLatLng = function(point) {
        var origin = this.pixelOrigin_;
        var lng = (point.x - origin.x) / this.pixelsPerLonDegree_;
        var latRadians = (point.y - origin.y) / -this.pixelsPerLonRadian_;
        var lat = Math.abs((2*Math.atan(Math.exp(latRadians))-Math.PI/2)*180/Math.PI);
        var Zu = lat/(180/Math.PI);
        var Zum1 = Zu+1;
        var exct = 0.0818197;
        var yy = -Math.abs(((point.y)-128));
        while (Math.abs(Zum1-Zu)>0.0000001){
        Zum1 = Zu;
        Zu = Math.asin(1-((1+Math.sin(Zum1))*Math.pow(1-exct*Math.sin(Zum1),exct))
                       / (Math.exp((2*yy)/-(256/(2*Math.PI)))*Math.pow(1+exct*Math.sin(Zum1),exct)));
        }
        if (point.y>256/2) {
            lat=-Zu*180/Math.PI;
        } else {
            lat=Zu*180/Math.PI;
        }
        return new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    };

    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the `projection` property can't be set via the `ImageMapTypeOptions` and has to be assigned after the `ImageMapType` has been constructed, this jsfiddle now works: http://jsfiddle.net/VkGjq/2/

```
var yandexMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType(
                     {getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
                         return "http://vec0"+((coord.x+coord.y)%5)+".maps.yandex.net/tiles?l=map&v=2.16.0&x=" + 
                             coord.x + "&y=" + coord.y + "&z=" + zoom + "";
                     },
                      tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
                      isPng: true,
                      alt: "Yandex",
                      name: "Yandex",
                      maxZoom: 17});
// projection is ignored if passed to MapTypeOptions
yandexMapType.projection = new YandexProjection();
map.mapTypes.set("Yandex", yandexMapType);
```

Answer (score 0):

By [license agreement](https://yandex.ru/legal/maps_api/) you can't use yandex maps without yandex api. You can't use yandex tiles in leaflet.

You need to wrap yandex api or use http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html

Or write own a wrapper.

Example https://all-maps.herokuapp.com/

https://github.com/artamonovdev/all-maps